# Storm cluster setup locally - not getting executed

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am trying to run zookeeper, nimbus and supervisor on same machine to simulate storm cluster (I understand storm is designed as distributed system but for learning want to simulate how things works in single machine).

Zookeeper, Nimbus and Supervisor started well without errors and I submitted one of storm-starter topology (RollingTopWords). storm.yaml has both zookeeper and nimbus pointing to 127.0.0.1. Nimbus got the topology and seems to initiate download to supervisor but some reason do not see any execution on supervisor. Supervisor log is also empty other than startup messages.

Nimbus log is below (last few ones) and after that I do not see any thing.

`2019-12-13 02:43:01.818 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Assigning top1-1-1576204977 to 1 slots
2019-12-13 02:43:01.818 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Assign executors: [[14, 14], [12, 12], [10, 10], [8, 8], [6, 6], [4, 4], [2, 2], [7, 7], [5, 5], [3, 3], [1, 1], [15, 15], [13, 13], [11, 11], [9, 9]]
2019-12-13 02:43:01.819 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Fragmentation after scheduling is: 0.0 MB, 0 PCore CPUs
2019-12-13 02:43:01.819 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Node Id: 1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3 Total Mem: 4096.0, Used Mem: 1920.0, Available Mem: 2176.0, Total CPU: 400.0, Used CPU: 150.0, Available CPU: 250.0, fragmented: false
2019-12-13 02:43:01.819 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Setting new assignment for topology id top1-1-1576204977: Assignment(master_code_dir:storm-local, node_host:{1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3=centos-7-1.asia-southeast1-b.c.mandava-forever.internal}, executor_node_port:{[14, 14]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [12, 12]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [10, 10]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [8, 8]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [6, 6]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [4, 4]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [2, 2]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [7, 7]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [5, 5]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [3, 3]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [1, 1]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [15, 15]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [13, 13]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [11, 11]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700]), [9, 9]=NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700])}, executor_start_time_secs:{[2, 2]=1576204981, [4, 4]=1576204981, [6, 6]=1576204981, [8, 8]=1576204981, [10, 10]=1576204981, [12, 12]=1576204981, [14, 14]=1576204981, [1, 1]=1576204981, [3, 3]=1576204981, [5, 5]=1576204981, [7, 7]=1576204981, [9, 9]=1576204981, [11, 11]=1576204981, [13, 13]=1576204981, [15, 15]=1576204981}, worker_resources:{NodeInfo(node:1a8a2795-2b6f-4529-862c-61c45d7bf536-10.148.0.3, port:[6700])=WorkerResources(mem_on_heap:1920.0, mem_off_heap:0.0, cpu:150.0, shared_mem_on_heap:0.0, shared_mem_off_heap:0.0, resources:{onheap.memory.mb=1920.0, cpu.pcore.percent=150.0, offheap.memory.mb=0.0}, shared_resources:{})}, total_shared_off_heap:{}, owner:root)
2019-12-13 02:43:02.849 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus pool-29-thread-41 [INFO] Created download session 2e19912c-f36f-4eb6-9b1e-df51b94adb24 for top1-1-1576204977-stormjar.jar
2019-12-13 02:43:02.851 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus pool-29-thread-39 [INFO] Created download session 1798dab4-32d0-4112-b20e-e7b96eee4eaf for top1-1-1576204977-stormcode.ser
2019-12-13 02:43:02.859 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus pool-29-thread-34 [INFO] Created download session b0523592-8374-43f1-b536-22c724bb8836 for top1-1-1576204977-stormconf.ser`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out - it is actually running and execution logs are stored in each worker log of storm.
On my set up it is getting logged in /logs/workers-artifacts/-x-xxxx/670x/worker.log

670X refers to workers port no on supervisor. For example worker1 would have 6701 etc.